# Not able to compile complete in Magento2

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile

I am running compile command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Compilation was started.
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% < 1 sec 54.0 MiB  You have new mail in /var/mail/root

Compilation stop in 1/7 without displaying any error.

May i know why its breaking compilation ?

Comment: Check the memory limit, script execution time of your server. Also check for any malformed xml files in any of your newly installed modules.

Comment: which PHP version to use?

Comment: use php bin/magento setup:di:compile  -vvv  to display error if any.

Comment: @Ansar Husain did you find any solution?
How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Could be memory-related?

Try increasing the memory limit:

```
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile
```